# ajax javascript check box change not working

Tags: java, javascript, php, ajax, jquery

I am using the following ajax javascript to pass values if checkbox  is checked or not, The problem which I am facing is that it is working only for the first row from the mysql fetch aray and for the rest of the results it always sends checkboxstatus = 1 as a result, no matter if the chekbox is checkied or not. here is the code:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(e) {
   $('input[name=status]').change(function(){
    if( $('input[name=status]').prop('checked') )
       {checkboxstatus = '1';}
       else
       {checkboxstatus = '0';}
        var idm = $(this).attr('idm');
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "checkboxtestbackend.php",
        data: {"checkboxstatus": checkboxstatus,
        "idm":idm 
       },
        })        
        .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){alert(jqXHR+"--"+textStatus+"--"+errorThrown);});
    });//end change
  });//end ready
</script>
```

Usualy all the checkgoxes are checked in the first sql fetch if I uncehck the checbox it POST's 0 as value , but for the rest of the sql fetch results it always sends "1" as a POST result no matter checked or not.

this is the code which shows the checkboxes: `<?php echo "<input type='checkbox' idm='$idm' name='status'"; if($row['status'] == 1){print "checked='checked'"; }echo "/>";?>`

The visualizations of the status of the checkboxes is working but the change it is not.

This is the sql query fot it:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM cursos ORDER BY id DESC";
if (!$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
    die("Error: " . mysqli_error($con));
}


<?php

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{   
    $idm = $row['id'];
?>

<td align="center"><?php echo "<input type='checkbox' idm='$idm' name='status'"; if($row['status'] == 1){print "checked='checked'"; }echo "/>";?></td>
```

Comment: I'm confused.  You mention `mysql fetch aray` but I don't see any PHP in the post.  Are the checkboxes being printed wrong?

Comment: question updated, the checboxes are printed ok, but problem is the java script trgger, when it should sent checkboxstatus = 0 it sent's it always = 1, it workis only for the first result from the database, for the rest's it ways working as checkboxstatus = 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me...

I changed `$('input[name=status]').prop('checked')` to `$(this).prop('checked')`.

```
<input type="checkbox" idm="stuff" name="status" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" idm="stuff" name="status" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" idm="stuff" name="status" value="3">  

<script>
 $(document).ready(function(e) {
$('input[name=status]').change(function(){
    if( $(this).prop('checked') ) {checkboxstatus = '1';}
                             else {checkboxstatus = '0';}
        var idm = $(this).attr('idm'); 
        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "checkboxtestbackend.php",
           data: {"checkboxstatus": checkboxstatus, "idm":idm },
           success: function(response){
              console.log(response);  
             }
        })        
        .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){alert(jqXHR+"--"+textStatus+"--"+errorThrown);});
});//end change
});//end ready 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this,

```
  $(document).ready(function(e) {
     $('.CheckBoxClass').click(function(){  // added class based event  
           if( $(this).is(':checked')) {
               checkboxstatus = '1';
             } else {
               checkboxstatus = '0';
              }             
             var idm = $(this).attr('idm');
                 $.ajax({
                     type: "POST",
                     url: "checkboxtestbackend.php",
                     data: {"checkboxstatus": checkboxstatus,
                        "idm":idm 
                        },
                 })        
             .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){alert(jqXHR+"--"+textStatus+"--"+errorThrown);});
            });//end click
     });//end ready
```

In PHP code,  added  class='CheckBoxClass'

```
<?php   
    echo "<input type='checkbox' idm='$idm' class='CheckBoxClass' name='status'"; if($row['status'] == 1){ print "checked='checked'"; }echo "/>";
?>
```